# How set unique in hbm config of NHibernate by allowe null value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, constraints, unique

I have a project using NHibernate by a Asset class.  Hbm config for this class is :

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Domain" namespace="Domain.Entities">
  <class name="Asset" table="Table_Asset" >

    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Code" unique="true"/>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Code column in this class is unique but value of this column could be Null. So the null value for code can not insert for second time.
I changed related constraint in `SQL` by Add a `Where` Condition :

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Asset_Code] ON [dbo].[Table_Asset] 
(
    [Code] ASC
)
WHERE ([Code] IS NOT NULL)
```

My problem is resolved by this change, but I need to a solution for set this type of unique in my hbm config. 
How I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add 'where' attribute to your hbm:

```
`<class name="Asset" table="Table_Asset" where="[Code] IS NOT NULL">`
```